# InterpolatingFunction within Piecewise gives range error?

Tags: interpolation, piecewise

So I have a function `myfun` with positive domain that I got from NDSolve and a bunch of transformations afterwards. I can plot it on its own like

```
Plot[myfun[t], {t, 0, 6}]
```

but when I try to insert it into a Piecewise function like

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{myfun[t], t > 0 && t < 6}}], {t, -6, 6}]
```

or

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{myfun[t], t > 0 && t < 6}, {1, t<=0}}], {t, -6, 6}]
```

it gives me warnings

```
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-5.99975} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
```

and doesn't plot the function `myfun`.

What is even more weird, I was unable to create a minimal working example, because something like

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}][t], 
t > 0 && t < 6}}], {t, -6, 6}]
```

works just fine!

What could be the problem here?

**EDIT**:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{Sqrt[Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}][t]], t > 1 && t < 6}}], {t, -6, 6}]
```

generates the same warnings, but does draw the plot. (Note that domain and range of the function under square root are positive.)

**EDIT 2**: Here's reduced code that has the problem

```
soln = NDSolve[{y'[t] == 1/(1/(1 + Cos[y[t]]))^2, y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]

pw = Piecewise[{{1, t < 0}, {y[t] /. soln, t > 0}}]
```

Now

```
Plot[pw /. x -> t, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

works but

```
Plot[pw /. x -> t, {t, -1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

doesn't.

Comment: Can you find a (hopefully simpler) `NDSolve[]`-generated `InterpolatingFunction[]` that generates that error?

Comment: No warning in v8.0.4 and v9.0.1 with the code in **EDIT**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit to add fix for plot not appearing*

I *think* the issue here is the way you are evaluating the `Piecewise` function.  If you look at the Scope part of the `Piecewise` documentation it says that to evaluate a piecewise funtion you should use a `ReplaceAll`, like this:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{Sin[x]/x, x < 0}, {1, x == 0}}, -x^2/100 + 1];
pw /. {{x -> -5}, {x -> 0}, {x -> 5}}
(*{Sin[5]/5, 1, 3/4}*)
```

This way the piecewise is constructed, then the variable (in this case x) is input.  The way you have written it substitutes the variable and then constructs the piecewise.  So to make your plot work correctly, you could write this:

```
p = Piecewise[{{Sqrt[Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}][t]], t > 1 && t < 6}}];
Plot[p /. {t -> x}, {x, -6, 6}]
```

[image: Piecewise plot]

To fix the issue with incorrect evaluation, again I think you need to define the piecewise function in the correct order.  In the original code (apologies for screenshot, formatting the symbol is hard):

[image: Piecewise1]

Notice the curly brackets (`List`) around the interpolating function?  If you use `First` to get rid of this the plot works.  Also note that in the `ReplaceAll` you should replace the variable in the piecewise function (i.e. t) with the variable you are plotting over (i.e. x) rather than the other way round.  So the result:

```
soln = NDSolve[{y'[t] == 1/(1/(1 + Cos[y[t]]))^2, y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
pw = Piecewise[{{1, t < 0}, {First[y[t] /. soln], t > 0}}];
Plot[pw /. t -> x, {x, -1, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, All}]
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks, this does make the warnings go away, but my original problem persists (see **EDIT 2**).

Comment: Edited to add detail

Answer (score 4):

**Only simple fixes are needed.**

Regarding the first edit - add `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}][t]], 
     t > 1 && t < 6}}], {t, -6, 6}]
```

[image]

Regarding the second edit - add `First`; no need for replacements in either case:

```
soln = First@
   NDSolve[{y'[t] == 1/(1/(1 + Cos[y[t]]))^2, y[0] == 0}, 
    y, {t, 0, 10}];
pw = Piecewise[{{1, t < 0}, {y[t] /. soln, t > 0}}];
plot2 = Plot[pw, {t, -1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Either one of the fixes, or both combined should work for your original problem as well.